# rewrite the MStest.exe command in such a way that it references the DLL containing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, mstest, coded-ui-tests

All:

For a project, we have to run mstest.exe from Visual Studio prompt commandline:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\OutDir>"c:\Program Fil
es\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"C:\Progr
am Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\OutDir\blahblahCUITChrome.dll"
```

However, the above statement gives me the following error:
    Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Loading C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\OutDir\blahblahC
UITChrome.dll...
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\OutDir\blahblahCUITChrom
e.dll
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramewor
k, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

It's so strange, I've already ensured that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll exists in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\OutDir\
```

How should we rewrite the aforementioned MStest.exe command in such a way that it references the DLL containing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework  ?

*Update:*

I moved the above mstest command into a msbuild csproj file:

I also included the following reference tag:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll"</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

However, it still fails.

How should we references the DLL containing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @hans-passant you seem to know msbuild and mstest quite well. could you please help me the problem that I described in my post?  I'm really need it for my project.

Comment: There's a chance, that the version of the assembly file that you ensured existed in the directory was different from the one that the test assembly is looking for (*Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a*)